# How do i make an image follow the cursor with html css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a site for a photography company and one of the things they want is an image gallery to follow the cursor like this:

[image: Image movement over cursor]


So basically when the cursor moves over the image, (`.image:hover`) the image should follow the cursor until the cursor is off hover and return back to normal position.

```
<style>
.image {
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
grid-row: 1;
grid-column: 1;
border: 5px solid black;
margin-left: 2px;
opacity: 0.7;
]
.image:hover {
width: 60%;
height: 60%;
opacity: 1;
border: 2px solid black;
display: flex;
}
</style>
<div class="image">
<img src="photoComp.jpg" />
</div>
```

now, that absolutely works, but then you need scripting. I am not so good at scripting, only up to cookies. So how can I script the image to follow the cursor and rotate and translate?

Thank you,

Ring Games

Have a look at this site. It is where I found the example:

http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/demo-photographer.html

Comment: If the image follows the cursor, how can the cursor ever gets out of the image?

Comment: @Anakin The image rotates and translates to the cursor. I will display an image in the edit